# Is there a way to generate generic method with nswag?

Tags: c#, generics, swagger, nswag

Im using nswag with a angular2 typescript application and would like to return a generic type or 'any' in typescript from the WebAPI:

```
public async Task<T> GetSomeInput(SomeInput input)
{
        if (input == "Car")
        {
            var result = await _repository.GetAsync<Car>(input);
            return result.MapTo<CarDto>();
        }

         if (input == "Bike")
        {
            var result = await _repository.GetAsync<Bike>(input);
            return result.MapTo<BikeDto>();
        }
   }
```

So in the angular side i make the cast. Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score -1):

If you use the full stack of nswag (swagger and code gen) you can just define the response as object and it should be typed as any in typescript.

Comment: Actually a tried it, and swagger seems to make it a void method.

Comment: Can you post a sample controller?

Comment: Btw: NSwag also supports inheritance with a base class

Comment: the example is the same in the OP but returning Task<object> instead Task<T>

Comment: And the swagger spec is generated by nswag?